# How to use JQuery's .trigger() with an element which I don't have access to the source code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a little help figuring out JQuery's `.trigger()` function. I'm working with a web browser plugin with utterly impenetrable source code. The main.js file contains thousands of lines of single-spaced code that all runs together, so it's virtually unreadable. Therefore, directly accessing any functions within the plugin is not an option.

I need to trigger a div that acts like a button that's displayed on the browser within the plugin. I have the element's ID, so I can access it via jQuery. To me, I think the simplest way to get that div to fire whatever function is associated with it is to use `.trigger("click")` on that div element. However, based on the documentation and me tooling around with it, it seems `.trigger("click")` only work if you set up the target div with:

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "click", function(){...});
```

Is there a way to get `.trigger("click")` to work on an element that I really can't otherwise manipulate?

Comment: You are writing plugin for which browser ?

Comment: Working in Firefox but could do it in Chrome too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the following?

```
$('#foo').click();
```

*Source:*

- https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: The thing is I want this element to fire without clicking the element itself. I basically want to click another element on the page and doing that fires the functions associated with the element I can't access. Essentially I click a button I insert into the page and it acts as if I click that other button.

Answer (score 0):

The native DOM has its own [`HTMLElement.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click#Browser_compatibility) distinct from jQuery's version, which may work better for you. See the below examples comparing the two (the difference is mainly in how events bubble, as far as I can tell):

```js
$('.trigger1a').on("mouseup", function() {
  $('#foo').click();
});
$('.trigger1b').on("mouseup", function() {
  $('#bar').click();
});

$('.trigger2a').on("mouseup", function() {
  document.getElementById('foo').click();
});
$('.trigger2b').on("mouseup", function() {
  document.getElementById('bar').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="trigger1a">jQuery "click" div</button>
<button class="trigger1b">jQuery "click" input</button>
<br>
<button class="trigger2a">DOM "click" div</button>
<button class="trigger2b">DOM "click" input</button>
<br>

<div class="bubblecatcher" onclick="console.log('event bubbled');">
  <div id="foo" onclick="console.log('div clicked');">Div with click event</div>
  <input id="bar" onclick="console.log('input clicked');" value="input with click event">
</div>
```

If that doesn't work for you either, you could fall all the way back to [creating your own `MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) and triggering it with `dispatchEvent` (note no jQuery here at all):

```js
function triggerClick() {
  var clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true
  });
  var clickEvent = document.getElementById('foo').dispatchEvent(clickEvent); 
}
```

```html
<div id="foo" onclick="alert('clicked');">div with click event</div>

<button class="trigger" onclick="triggerClick()">Click this to trigger it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

https://jsfiddle.net/zkLbwarj/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


$("body").on("click","a.unreachable",function(e){
e.preventDefault();
 $(this).text("Hammer Time!")
});

$("body").on("click",".proxy-button",function(){

$(".unreachable").trigger("click").css({"background-color":"red"});


})


});
```

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  border-radius:10px;
  padding:10px 15px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.proxy-button {
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<a class="button unreachable">Can't Touch This</a> <br>
<a class="button proxy-button">Proxy Button</a>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Your first jQuery function executes something you wrote within the handler. I need the functions I don't have access to execute.

Comment: so you're saying the functions you need to fire off are not attached to an event? That's what trigger does, it manually forces a browser event.